# With Cognos Report Studio, how do I count based on a rolling 28 day period that starts on a Monday?

Tags: sql, cognos

I analyze based on 28 day periods that begin on Mondays. I am making a daily report that tells me call information, as well as how many calls I have per address based on the current reporting period until the date the information was pulled for.

The details of the data (i.e. call description, primary key of call) will be specific to a 1 day period for the main query. The second joined query, will have a count of calls per address for a rolling 28 day period.

Thus, my main query for just 4/30. My joined query will start from 3 Mondays ago (Monday 4/6) until 4/30 (main query).

I do not know how to type in SQL to Cognos. I use detail filter expressions to set up my queries.

Answer (score 0):

At a high level the filter could be [Date] between [Date] and _add_days([Date],-28)